# Using BinaryJS over SSL raises security exceptions

Tags: node.js, ssl, websocket

My HTML file is served over HTTPS. When the page connects to a regular (i.e., insecure) web socket, many browsers will complain about "mixed content" (i.e., secure HTTPS with insecure WS). Chrome actually tells me this in so many words:

```
binary.min.js:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://ppr.cs.dal.ca:3004/client.html' was loaded over HTTPS, 
but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://ppr.cs.dal.ca:3003/bs'. 
This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.
    
binary.min.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': 
An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.
```

So, I tried setting up a secure BinaryJS socket and connecting to it (based on this [GitHub post](https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs/issues/113) and [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945634/secure-websocket-using-node-js-and-binary-js)). But, both Firefox and Chrome are complaining.

My server code:

```
const static = require('node-static');
const https = require('https');
const BinaryServer = require('binaryjs').BinaryServer;
const fs = require('fs');

const file = new(static.Server)();
const server = https.createServer(
    { key: fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem'), cert: fs.readFileSync('fullchain.pem') }, 
    (req, res) => { file.serve(req, res); }
).listen(3004, '0.0.0.0', () => {
        console.log("listening on :3004");
});

var bs = new BinaryServer({server: server, port: 3003, path: '/bs'});
bs.on('connection', (client) => {
        console.log('client connection');
        // ...
})
```

My client code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="binary.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
const client = new BinaryClient("wss://ppr.cs.dal.ca:3003/bs");
client.on('open', () => {
        const stream = client.createStream();
        // ...
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Firefox gives the following error:

```
The connection was refused when attempting to contact wss://ppr.cs.dal.ca:3003/bs.
```

Chrome:

```
binary.min.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://ppr.cs.dal.ca:3003/bs' failed: 
Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`
```

Unsure what to try next. It doesn't seem like BinaryJS is being very actively maintained.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945634/secure-websocket-using-node-js-and-binary-js) says that I could use a proxy but I'm targeting real-time communication so that seems like a huge overhead.

Maybe switching to "regular" websockets could be an option? ..

**EDIT** I'm getting the exact same problem when using regular websockets (i.e., no BinaryJS). So, this seems more related to WebSockets than anything else? ..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone - it seems like there is an easy fix. The problem was the BinaryServer port number; when it's the same as the HTTPS server, there's no problem. In hindsight, this is quite obvious (but, it did work this way without SSL) .. (the WebSockets solution also works when using the same port number)

For completeness, I'm posting a working version here:

client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="binary.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
const client = new BinaryClient("wss://ppr.cs.dal.ca:3004/bs");
client.on('open', () => {
        const stream = client.createStream();
        stream.on('data', e => console.log(JSON.stringify(e)));
        stream.write("hello world");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

server:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const static = require('node-static');
const https = require('https');
const BinaryServer = require('binaryjs').BinaryServer;
const { Writable} = require('stream');

const file = new(static.Server)();
const server = https.createServer({
  cert: fs.readFileSync('fullchain.pem'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem')
}, (req, res) => {
        file.serve(req, res);
});

class TestSink extends Writable {
        _write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(chunk));
        }
}

const bs = new BinaryServer({server: server, path: '/bs'});
bs.on('connection', (client) => {
        console.log('connection');
        client.on('stream', (stream, meta) => {
                console.log('stream start');
                const sink = new TestSink();
                stream.pipe(sink);
        });
});
```

Maybe it can help someone get started with BinaryJS over SSL.